# How do i append from one list to each item in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to python and am trying to create a new list from 2 other lists by appending each item in the list.

```
for number in num:

    for names in name:

        print(number+names)


num = [1,2,3,4,5]

name = ['Tom','Bob','Dave']

new_desired_list = [1Tom,1Bob,1Dave,2Tom,2Bob,2Data,3Tom,3Bob,3Dave..etc]
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want the cartesian product of both lists. For that you have [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). In order to join the strings you could use string formatting:

```
from itertools import product

[f'{i}{j}' for i,j in product(num, name)]
# ['{}{}'.format(i,j) for i,j in product(num, name)] # for Python 3.6< 
# ['1Tom', '1Bob', '1Dave', '2Tom', '2Bob'...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try appending a list ;)

```
l = []

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

names = ['Tom','Bob','Dave']

for number in numbers:
    for name in names:
        l.append(str(number) + str(name))

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
new_list = [str(i)+x for i in num for x in name]
```

Example:

```
>>> num = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> name = ['Tom','Bob','Dave']
>>> 
>>> new_list = [str(i)+x for i in num for x in name]
>>> new_list
['1Tom', '1Bob', '1Dave', '2Tom', '2Bob', '2Dave', '3Tom', '3Bob', '3Dave', '4Tom', '4Bob', '4Dave', '5Tom', '5Bob', '5Dave']
>>>
```